# In SAS EG how can we stop showing unwanted tables and outputs in the result workspace

Tags: sas

I created a table with header as 'Name' using the following:

```
data have;
input Name $;
cards;
DATE
DIAM
ET
PXMC
PWC
PWSC
Site
Time
TPMC
SF
;
run;
```

And transposed the table using the following code...

```
proc sql noprint;
 select name into : varlist separated by ' ' from have;
quit;

data transposed_table;
length &varlist 8;
do _n_=1 to 2;
   output;
end;
run;
```

The result of above is as below

```
DATE    DIAM    ET  PXMC    PWC PWSC    Site    Time    TPMC    SF
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Further I used the following code to delete all unwanted table from my workspace..

```
Proc Delete Data = work.have;    *This will delete 'have' from work;
 run;
```

I am still getting **'SAS report - program'** in the workspace, how can i stop this from appearing on my workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohhh what I was looking was so simple... wow.

```
ods noresults; /* just place this before code wherever no such report output is needed */
```

It worked.